# Как удалить селектор из чужого класса?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть чужая разметка:

```
<тег class="alien">
```

и есть чужой css файл:

```
.alien {
   color: red;
   width: 100px;
}
```

Нужно удалить селектор color из класса alien не изменяя чужого css файла и разметки.

Как это можно сделать?

желательно средствами css.

но можно использовать и javascript

Answer (score 2):

```css
.alien {
  color: initial !important;
}
```

Comment: Значение initial применяется для установки исходного значения свойства. Мне дефолтное значение не надо, а нужно вообще удалить этот селектор.

Answer (score -1):

Удалить не получится, но вы можете подключить свой css файл после вражеского и перегрузить .alien -

```css
alien{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<alien>Black as body</alien>
<style>
  alien{
    color: inherit;
  }
</style>
```